# What is this shrub with shiny green leaves?

Tags: identification, shrubs

In a west European city in front of an office building I found this plant which for some reason has many spider webs built on it.

The shrub has about 70 cm height but clearly pruned.

Any idea what it is?
[image]

Comment: I don't suppose you've ever noticed any flowers on it, maybe around spring time?

Comment: No, I have never seen any flowers!

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities are *Skimmia japonica* and a smaller *Prunus laurocerasus* (cherry laurel) cultivar such as "Otto Luyken" or "Zabeliana". All of these are widely used in commercial landscaping. Wait and see what the flowers are like when they eventually appear.